# How to allow underscore in email regex in coldfusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion

hi i am using the regex to validate the email but when i try to user underscore in email address than is giving me the error.

Following is regx which i am using.

^[a-zA-Z0-9-'+~]+(.[a-zA-Z0-9-'+~]+)*@([a-zA-Z_0-9-]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,10}$

```
if (not isValid("regex", arguments.propertyValue,"^[a-zA-Z0-9-'\+~]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-'\+~]+)*@([a-zA-Z_0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,10}$")) {
}
```

can any one please let me know which regx should i use?

Comment: Tons of variants, go check the 2 threads  I linked to. Just a hint: `[a-zA-Z0-9-'\+~]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-'\+~]+)*` does not match a `_`. Why not add it inside `[...]`?

Comment: This question should be opened, as the correct answer is to not user a regex for validating email, but the builtin email validation.

Ironically, that's isValid("email", "someemail@something.com")